# What is a less extreme word for enforce?

Tags: single-word-requests

> "The university should stringently enforce the rules.",

What word can be used in the place of the word "enforce" to make this sentence less extreme?

Comment: Uphold? 3. To maintain or affirm: uphold a standard of behavior. Also why don't you start by removing "stringently" as Glorfindel suggested? "Stringently" only intensifies the enforcement, so you can start from there.

Comment: I agree that if you are going to replace *enforce*, you should also drop *stringently*. It makes no sense to say *stringently ponder*, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd rather drop the word [*stringently*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stringent) to make the sentence less extreme. *Enforce* has several [synonyms](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enforce#synonyms) but they'll all sound extreme next to *stringently*.

Answer (score 0):

Changing more than just the word *enforce*, you could say something like this:

> The university should be guided by the rules.

This is akin to saying that, everything being equal, the rules should be followed. However, the spirit of the rules should be considered and there may be some cases where they can be open to more than a strictly literal interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

A more neutral-sounding term is [promulgate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/promulgate).

> "to put (a law or rule) into action or force." (Mirriam-Webster dictionary).